# How do I populate a bash array with multi-line command output?

Tags: bash

How can I populate a bash array with multi-line command output?

For example given this printf command:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\n\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n\n'
a
b

c

d
e
f
```

I would like to have a bash array populated as if I wrote:

```
$ arr[0]='a
b'
$ arr[1]='c'
$ arr[2]='d
e
f'
```

and so could loop through it as:

```
$ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do printf "<%s>\n" "$i"; done
<a
b>
<c>
<d
e
f>
```

I have tried various incarnations of using a NUL character to separate my intended array fields instead of a blank line as that seems like my best bet but no luck so far, e.g.:

```
$ IFS=$'\0' declare -a arr="( $(printf 'a\nb\n\0c\n\0d\ne\nf\n\0') )"
$ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do printf "<%s>\n" "$i"; done
<a>
<b>
<c>
<d>
<e>
<f>
```

I also tried `mapfile -d $'\0'` but my mapfile doesn't support `-d`.

I did find that this works:

```
$ declare -a arr="( $(printf '"a\nb" "c" "d\ne\nf"') )"
$ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do printf "<%s>\n" "$i"; done
<a
b>
<c>
<d
e
f>
```

but that seems a little clunky and I'd have to escape `"`s when all I really want it to tell the shell to use some character other than a blank as the array fields separator.

Comment: FYI, `mapfile` in `bash` 4.4 supports `-d` and was released today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A best-practice approach, using NUL delimiters:

```
arr=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do
  arr+=( "$item" )
done < <(printf 'a\nb\n\0c\n\0d\ne\nf\n\0')
```

...which would be even simpler with bash 4.4:

```
mapfile -t -d '' arr < <(printf 'a\nb\n\0c\n\0d\ne\nf\n\0')
```

Much more crudely, supporting the double-newline separator approach:

```
item=''
array=( )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line ]]; then
    if [[ $item ]]; then
      item+=$'\n'"$line"
    else
      item="$line"
    fi
  else
    [[ $item ]] && {
      array+=( "$item" )
      item=''
    }
  fi
done < <(printf 'a\nb\n\nc\n\nd\ne\nf\n\n')
```